# Using aspnetcore signalr as system.io stream blocking

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, signalr

I'm building a custom c# stream that is backed by signalr for a network transport (long story short I currently use a NetworkStream wrapped in SecureStream for encryption). I want to use signalr to pass byte[] blocks, but pass them through a SecureStream to encrypt them.

I'm nearly complete, but i'm running into an issue. The secureStream is doing a .read() call against my custom stream, the Stream.Read() method is a blocking call, since this is blocking, it's also blocking the Connection.On() method that is performing the read. Thus I have a deadlock.

The basic flow is:

```
public class SignalrStream : Stream
{

  public async Task ConnectAsync() {
      Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(ServerURI).Build();
      Connection.On<byte[]>("msg", (data) => { cache(data); });
      await Connection.StartAync()
  }

  public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
      while(true)
      {
          if (ConnectionClosed) { return 0;}
          if (DataInCache) { copyToBuffer(buffer); return length; } 
          //No data is cache. Block
          Thread.Sleep(100);
      }
  }
}
```

Since the Read() call is blocking, any incoming data doesn't get processed by the .On() function, thus the cache is never populated.

I've tried creating the HubConnectionBuilder on a separate thread, and tried doing the Read() call wrapped in a Task

```
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        Task<int> task = Task.Run(async () => { return await ReadBytesAsync(buffer,offset,count); });
        task.Wait();
        return task.Result;
    }
```

With no success.

Yes I know I could probably resolve this using async functions throughout the code, but I want to wrap in the SecureStream, which means I must implement the blocking Read() call.

Thoughts?

Comment: If SecureStream is your own class, why not just implement ReadAsync instead of Read?

Comment: SecureStream is a native .net class

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to dig up this subject, but I'm also trying to implement a SignalRStream.

In a first approach, I plan to use an [AutoResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent) (or manual maybe) to block the reading until usable data is obtained: For the moment I don't see how else to do it.

Could this idea help you? Or have you already solved your problem?

Comment: There's no reason to block at all. All Stream-derived classes have async methods anyway ant ASP.NET Core *really hates* blocking. Whatever the `SecureStream` class is, it's not a built-in .NET class

Comment: Yes, you're right, but the idea is that the customer can know when the data is available, so does an approach like NetworkStream.DataAvailable seem better to you?

Comment: No. The customer already knows because the await completes. There's no reason to block. *SignalR itself* requires tasks

Comment: Concerning SecureStream, for me it's another problem: as soon as each stream works separately, they can work together.

Comment: OK thanks Panagiotis Kanavos, I'll keep thinking about it then:)

Comment: The point is that the OP was trying to solve the wrong problem with a custom class. There's *no* reason to block

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, please check that you are answer the original question. I am aware that you are new on SO and you have not enough Rep to make comments. Keep in your mind that the idea of SO is a Q&A forum, not Q&Q&...

Comment: David, thank you, I take note of your remark, but I sincerely thought I would provide part of the answer to a question that didn't have one. Sorry if I didn't get it right.